# jboss 6.4 ignoring webapp directory structure

Tags: java

we are moving from jboss 5.1 to jboss 6.4 and i have below entries in my xxx.ear/META-INF/application.xml. it seems like jboss 6.4 is not able to identify webapp but when I change this to webapp.war then it is deployed, due to this I need to rename my webapp folder to webapp.war.

With jboss 5.1 it is working fine but jboss 6.4 needs this change, is their any way I can suppress this?

Application scripts needs update to rename webapp to webapp.war every where and I want to avoid it.

```
Thanks in advance.

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="1.4"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd">
  <display-name>Web App</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
    <web-uri>webapp</web-uri>
    <context-root>/app</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```